# WCF AJAX Cannot infer schema. The Request/Response body is wrapped

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

I'm working on connecting a web form to SSIS through a WCF Web Service.  My issue started out as an issue with cross-referencing the service, and it has now become an issue with the service giving an error as in the title.

Here is my code:

```
//Service
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExtractionService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/SubmitExtraction")]
    string runExtraction(string start, string end, string packageName);
}


public string runExtraction(string start, string end, string packageName)
    {
        //code to run SSIS package
    }

//Javascript
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var startDateTime = ($("#from").data + " 00:00:00");
    var endDateTime = ($("#to").data + " 23:59:59");
    var ExtractionData = {
        "start": startDateTime,
        "end": endDateTime,
        "packageName": $("#packageName").data
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ExtractionService.svc/runExtraction",
        data: JSON.stringify(ExtractionData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert("success..." + data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    })
})

//Global.asax.cs
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000" );
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}

//web.config
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IExtractionService" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:49313/ExtractionService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IExtractionService"
    contract="ExtractionServices.IExtractionService"        name="BasicHttpBinding_IExtractionService" />
  </client>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

This should be all you need.  If there is anything else, I can put that up.  I feel like it is something small.  I have been putting all of this together bit by bit and I know it can look very choppy, but I feel majority of it is in working order.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fixed my own issue.  Edited to show what was wrong.

Comment: If you fixed it you should create an answer explaining what you did, rather than edit your question. This makes it clearer for others who may have the same issue as you. I have rolled back you edit (don't worry, you can still retrieve it from the edit history http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31122001/revisions).

Comment: Added an answer below that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ajax call, where I accessed the url, I put in the method name as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ExtractionService.svc/runExtraction",
    data: JSON.stringify(ExtractionData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
```

The service had a uri specified that did not click in my head until after a second glance, when I changed the url to match the uri instead of the method name as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ExtractionService.svc/SubmitExtraction",
    data: JSON.stringify(ExtractionData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
```